# Proper way of using the same button in multiple contextes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I implement a small webbased game with JavaScript:
When game over, a menu pops up with multiple buttons. One button returns the player to the main menu.
The same button shall appear when I interrupt the game.

```
                    <div class="menu gameOverMenu" style="display: none;">
                            <button class="menuButton" type="button" id ="playAgain">
                                    Play again
                            </button>
                            <button class="menuButton" type="button" id ="toMainMenu1">
                                    Main Menu
                            </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu pauseMenu" style="display: none;">
                            <button class="menuButton" type="button" id ="continue">
                                    Continue
                            </button>
                            <button class="menuButton" type="button" id ="toMainMenu2">
                                    Main Menu
                            </button>
                    </div>
```

and handle the button event to return to the main menu via jQuery:

```
        $('#toMainMenu1, #toMainMenu2' ).on('click', function(){
            switchUi("main");
        })
```

I don't want to use the same id again and creating a similar button with an other ID as I did does not feel right. Should I create the button with the display: none; property once in my markup and clone it into my different menus? Create a class for these two buttons? Or is there an easier and better way to do so?
I hope I follow the SO rules of posting, this is my first time asking for help.

Comment: Creating different buttons pointing to same event would be better

Comment: `I hope I follow the SO rules of posting,`  Not sure you have.  Main thing missing here is some code.. a small reproducible example etc.

Comment: Edited it. Hope it is alright now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an option:

```
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <div class="gameOverMenu" style="display: none;">
         <button class="menuButton" type="button" id ="playAgain">Play again</button>                    
    </div>
    <div class="pauseMenu" style="display: none;">
         <button class="menuButton" type="button" id ="continue">Continue</button>
    </div>
    <button class="menuButton" type="button" id="toMainMenu">Main Menu</button>
</div>
```

or do not use ID toMainMenu1 and 2 but use a class `nagivateToMainMenu` and use that in your jQuery `$("button.nagivateToMainMenu").on("click", function(){ switchUi("main"); });` etc.

```
<button class="menuButton nagivateToMainMenu" type="button" id="toMainMenu3000">Main Menu</button>
```